# does Silverlight have more graph/charting capabilities than WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, charts, out-of-browser

In terms of making a decision between WPF or Silverlight for an application does Silverlight have more graph/charting capabilities than WPF?  Would this be a factor (in terms of additional cost/effort with WPF to build/buy charting components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Silverlight does not have any better access to charting tools than WPF.  In terms of  commercial components WPF is likely to have a wider choice of charts.

What might be considered Silverlight's "native" charting components found in the Silvelight Toolkit are also available for WPF.

As far as factors to consider between WPF and Silvelight OOB it's not an issue.  The choice is much simpler than that.

- Is it desirable and possible to provide a significant chunk of the applications funcionality to users **in browser**, that is with all the sandbox security intact?
- Is it really important to reach Mac users?

If the answer to either of the above questions is yes then Silverlight OOB **might** be worth considering.  If not then go with WPF the job is likely to be easier.